# Is there a way to sort objects created through classes that is made up of both strings and integers in Python?

Tags: python, class, sorting

I have an assignment to create a deck of cards through the use of a class with methods that deal, shuffle, fan, order and checks if the deck is in order but I am having trouble creating the last one. The deck must be ordered by their values in each suit, and the suits ordered as Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, and then Spades. My code up to this point is found below:

```
import random

class Card():

    def __init__(self, value, suit):
        self.value = value
        self.suit = suit


    def show_card(self):
        print(str(self.value)+ " of " + str(self.suit))


class Deck():

    deck_of_cards = []
    cards_in_play = [] 
    draw_card = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.make_deck()      


    def make_deck(self):
        for suit in ['Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts', 'Spades']:
            for value in [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King', 'Ace']:
                self.deck_of_cards.append(Card(value,suit))
                self.cards_in_play.append(Card(value, suit))

    def shuffle(self):
        self.shuffled_deck = random.shuffle(self.cards_in_play)


    def fan(self):
        for card in self.cards_in_play:
            card.show_card()

    def deal(self):
        draw_card=self.cards_in_play.pop()
        draw_card.show_card()

    def order(self):
        for suit in ['Club', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts', 'Spades']:
            for value in [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King', 'Ace']:
                self.deck_of_cards.append(Card(value, suit))
                self.cards_in_play.append(Card(value, suit))
```

Comment: Look into buildin `sorted` functions and its `key` argument https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sortinghowto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some code fixes before we go on:

1. Universalize the `suits` and `values` list so that it can be used by all classes if needed.
2. Move `deck_of_cards` and `cards_in_play` *inside* the `__init__` function. If you do not, this is called a ["class attribute"](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects) and will make it so every class has that value if not initialized (likely something you do not intend).

```py
class Test:
    a = 10

t1 = Test
t2 = Test

t1.a = 11
print(t2.a) # >>> 11
```

3. `random.shuffle()` is a function that runs in place. In other words, it returns `None`, but modifies the list given to it.

```py
import random

l = ["a", "b", "c"]
print(random.shuffle(l)) # >>> None
print(l) # >>> [b, c, a]
```

4. Don't print things -- return them. It will make your code not only clearer, but also more useful. If you want to print something that a function returns, just simply print the return.

```py
def deal(self):
    draw_card = self.cards_in_play.pop()
    return draw_card
```

5. Familiarize yourself with `sort` and the `__lt__` (detail below).

---

```py
import random
suits = ['Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts', 'Spades']
values = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King', 'Ace']

class Card:
    def __init__(self, value, suit):
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = value

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if suits.index(self.suit) > suits.index(other.suit):
            return False

        if values.index(self.value) > values.index(other.value):
            return False

        return True

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.value} of {self.suit}"

class Deck:
    def __init__(self):    
        self.deck_of_cards = []
        self.cards_in_play = []

        self.make_deck()

    def make_deck(self):
        for suit in suits:
            for value in values:
                self.deck_of_cards.append(Card(value,suit))
                self.cards_in_play.append(Card(value, suit))

    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.cards_in_play)

    def fan(self):
        for card in self.cards_in_play:
            print(card)

    def deal(self):
        draw_card = self.cards_in_play.pop()
        return draw_card

    def order(self):
        self.cards_in_play.sort()

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.cards_in_play)
```

Utilizing the magic method [`__lt__`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/operator.html#operator.__lt__) (less than), we can use the function `sort` to automatically sort a `class`. To make the point more clear, notice the following:

```py
# Your new `order` function.
def order(self):
    self.cards_in_play.sort()

# Implementing __lt__ now allows us to do the following comparison (which is what sort will use to sort your list of Card objects):
print(Card("Clubs", 2) > Card("Clubs", 3)) # True

# If you notice on docs, __ge__ (greater than), __eq__ (equal than), etc. can also be implemented to give you full flexibility.
```

Notice I also added the [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) function to both `Deck` and `Card` so that you can instead more simply do:

```py
card = Card("Clubs", 2)
print(card) # >>> 2 of Clubs
```

---

Edit: @Discussion below.

```py
suits = ['Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts', 'Spades']
values = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King', 'Ace']

class Card:
    def __init__(self, value, suit):
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = value

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if suits.index(self.suit) > suits.index(other.suit):
            return False

        if values.index(self.value) > values.index(other.value):
            return False

        return True

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.suit == other.suit and self.value == other.value:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.value} of {self.suit}"
```

With the new `__eq__` method, we can use the `==` sign between classes.

```py
c1 = Card(2, "Clubs")
c2 = Card(2, "Diamonds")
c3 = Card(2, "Diamonds")

print(c1 == c2) # False
print(c1 > c2) # False
print(c1 < c2) # True
print(c2 == c3) # True
```

This allows us to compare the `Card`s with ease.

Comment: Thank you Felipe, this was helpful and thank you for laying out somethings I should look into and learn myself. I was wondering if you knew a way to access the ranks you created. Would I create a new method or just a variable within the current card method

Comment: What do you mean by "rank"? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Sorry, I seem to have jumbled together several different assignments. what I meant was is there a way to use the suits.index(self.suit) > suits.index(other.suit) and values.index(self.value) > values.index(other.value) you placed in the __lt__. An addition part of my assignment is to compare the value of one card to another and I was wondering how I may go about using the values you created

Comment: Well, with the code above you can now compare `Card` values as it is. :) Notice at the bottom: `print(Card("Clubs", 2) > Card("Clubs", 3)) # True`. That is a comparison between two different cards, because we have "overloaded" the `>` and `<` sign with the function `__lt__`. If you wanted to, you can also overload the `__eq__` (equal to) to overload the `==` sign. Let me add example above, one sec.

Comment: Added example up above. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize your Card class as follows:

```
values = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King', 'Ace']
suits = ['Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts', 'Spades']

class Card:
    def __init__(self, value, suit):
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = value
        #if value order matters in first place
        self.rank = 4*values.index(self.value) + suits.index(self.suit)
        #else
        self.rank = 13*suits.index(self.suit) + values.index(self.value)
```

and create the check function as follows:

```
class Deck:
    def check(self):
        rank_before = self.cards_in_play[0].rank
        for card in self.cards_in_play[1:]:
            rank = card.rank
            if rank > rank_before:
                rank_before = rank
            else:
                return False
        return True
```

Answer (score -1):

The canonical way to handle this is to realize that you have two identities for the card: its play value and its display value.  You need a simple cognate to the `__repr__` function.

Very simply, value `value` with a simple rank integer, `card_rank`, 0-12.  The *display* value, what you print any time a *human* refers to it, is handled with a trivial translation list:

```
print_value = (
    '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10',
    'Jack', 'Queen', 'King', 'Ace'
)
```

Whenever you need to output a value, you simply use `print_value[card_rank]`.  Put this into the `__repr__` function of your `Card` class.

With this partitioning of functionality, sorting by `card_rank` solves your problem without further ado.

Comment: Man... even I, who has been programming in Python for a long while, don't understand what you mean. Are you suggesting to rank the cards via a list `print_value`? I'm confused...

Comment: @Felipe: you sort by card_rank, values 0 through 12.  The values '2' through "Ace" are *only* display values.